# drawing inside a qt windows

Tags: c++, qt, qt4

I'd like to draw a color "frame" within a QT window. So, I have

```
setFixedSize(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
```

and I'd like to draw, say, a red (filled) border within width and height. Could anyone help me out?

Comment: What have you tried already so no effort is wasted by us unpaid code monkeys.

Comment: @phresnel: Heh. Well, I don't know where to start. I have the window, with the background color that I want, and it's compiling fine. That's all I have.

Comment: From you other questions it seems you are not too well versed in google-searches: https://www.google.de/#q=qt+draw+rect+onto+window , which leads me to http://doc.qt.digia.com/qt/painting-basicdrawing.html .

Comment: @phresnel: Well, someone has to get the karma of answering question, and someone has to ask those questions. Thanks for the links!

Answer (score 0):

Depends on a couple of things:

- Is it a border around an existing widget? If it's just a border around an existing widget don't go down the route of painting it yourself, it's much simpler to use [Stylesheets](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/stylesheet-reference.html) than draw it.
- If of course you need a custom or very specific style, then you're best off drawing it using the [Painting System](http://doc.qt.digia.com/qt/paintsystem.html). I'd strongly suggest do it using stylesheets unless you do need specifics. The paint system can be a bit unwieldy for just adding a border to a widget.